# How to POST data from database to REST using JDeveloper 12c REST adapter?

Tags: database, oracle, rest, soa, jdeveloper

I'm having trouble getting some data from an Oracle database to POST using REST adapter in JDeveloper 12c. I'm still learning JDeveloper and I have only tried Database to File or File to Database but not yet doing this way. I have read some references but it doesn't show the same way as I wanted.

I'm getting this error which indicates that what I'm passing is not a valid JSON format from Database.

```
com.oracle.bpel.client.BPELFault: faultName: {{http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension}bindingFault} messageType: {{http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension}RuntimeFaultMessage} parts: {{ summary=unsupported variable Receive_receive_InputVariable in REST invoke} cause: {unsupported variable Receive_receive_InputVariable in REST invoke}
```

This is how my BPEL structure works.

Database Adapter --> BPEL (Transforms to JSON) --> REST (POST)

[image: Db to REST POST]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reading that `cause: {unsupported variable Receive_receive_InputVariable in REST invoke}` make me gess that your `BPEL (Transforms to JSON)` is wrong.

Comment: @Zorglube Yeah that's what I've said. Do you have any suggestions how can I transform it to valid JSON for REST adapter to process? See 3rd picture.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW I still haven't found a good way to fix this myself. I have tried doing what you did a while back, but I got the same issue. BPEL did not seem to have a good way to post valid JSON, it seemed to construe some sort of XML block around it. Did you eventually find out how this worked?